# Swift macro equivalent for type

Tags: swift, macros

I have a macro in Objective-C that encapsulates a type as follows:

```
 #define Type SInt16
```

I then use Type exclusively across the code and can even change it to Float should I need. How do I translate in Swift?

Comment: In vim: `:%s/Type/SInt16/g` ;-)

Comment: You should not have been using `#define` in the first place. This is a case for `typedef`

Answer (score 4):

Use a typealias:

```
typealias Type = SInt16
```